# How to include file in NodeJS SOAP request

Tags: node.js, file, soap, file-upload, npm

I am using the MERN stack and one of our requirements is to hit a SOAP web service from NodeJS. Part of this SOAP call includes a file upload. I have been using node-soap package (https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap). Is there an additional NPM package that I can use for this purpose, that is specifically to include a file in a SOAP request? As a backup how does SOAP handle files? Is there some way I can hack this, like convert it to base64 or something like that first? Any help is greatly appreciated. Versions below.

```
node -v v6.10.2
npm -v 3.10.10
soap@0.19.0
│ ├── compress@0.99.0
│ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question, especially after so much time. I hadn't used SOAP in a long, long time and never with Node so I failed to realize the question really is, how do you handle files in a SOAP request. My answer was to convert it to Base64 first. Something like:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync('picture_of_kittehs.jpg')
const fileBase64 = new Buffer(file).toString('base64')
```